# first and last name Assembly

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I am working on this one problem where I have to enter a first and lastname in one string separated by a space, display only the lastname. I created a program that I feel is close but instead of a prompt it is just a outmsg. I am not sure how i can prompt for the name and only the last displays. I am not sure if I only need to change one thing around. here is the code:

```
include irvine32.inc
title trial
.data
outmsg DB "Edward Magruder",0  
Space DB ' ',0
len    DW 0
.code
main proc
mov ebx, offset outmsg
mov edx, offset outmsg
call writestring
call crlf
sub eax,eax

mov ecx, lengthof outmsg
L2:
mov al,[ebx]
cmp al, Space
je goodToGo
add ebx, 1
loop l2
goodToGo:

add ebx, 1
showChar:
mov al, [ebx]
call writechar
add ebx, 1
cmp al, Space
loop showChar

Exit 
main endp
end main

//output
//Edward Magruder
//Magruder
```

Answer (score 0):

Irvine's [`ReadString`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Freadstring.htm) produces a zero-terminated string as you already used with `outmsg`. Therefore the first changes are minimal:

```
...
.code
main proc
lea edx, outmsg             ; Address of an buffer that receives the string
                            ;   ... same as `mov ebx, offset outmsg`
mov ecx, sizeof outmsg      ; Maximal number of characters to read
call ReadString
mov ecx, eax                ; Return value (EAX): strlen -> ECX for the loop L2
xor eax, eax                ; EAX=0 for the loop L2

mov ebx, offset outmsg      ; EBX points to outmsg for the loop L2
;mov edx, offset outmsg
;call writestring
;call crlf
;sub eax,eax

;mov ecx, lengthof outmsg
L2:
...
```

The next steps could be to output a text before the input ("Enter a name") with [`WriteString`](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Fwritestring.htm) and to define a bigger outmsg:

```
outmsg DB 32 DUP (0)        ; Reserve 32 bytes and fill them with 0
```

What's about names with two spaces ("Richard Milhous Nixon") or no space ("Lenin")?